# How to programmatically input value to devExtreme List search box and trigger the event that will filter the list as usual?

Tags: javascript, devextreme

any DevExtreme user here? I have a value that need to be input to the dxList search bar (not by user typing), what I want is set the search bar text box value and filter the list accordingly, where can I configure this? I mean the search bar must have an id right? Where can find the searchBarId and code like following?

```
document.getElementById("searchBarId").value = "ABC";
```

I have tried to get the HtmlCollection by following:

```
var textContainer = document.getElementByClassName("dx-texteditor-input-container")[0];
```

Then once I get it and I set the value

```
textContainer.value = "ABC"
```

The value is set but didn't trigger the filter function. Do I need to call the filter function manually? How to do that? Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the [`option(optionName, optionValue)`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxList/Methods/#optionoptionName_optionValue) method on the dx-list instance to set the [`searchValue`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxList/Configuration/#searchValue) property.

Example:

```
var listWidget = $("#list").dxList({
    dataSource: products,
    searchEnabled: true,
    searchExpr: "Name",
    displayExpr: "Name"
}).dxList("instance");

listWidget.option('searchValue', 'my search input');
```